# Unfortunately the app stopped working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an android app. When the user signup I want to store the signup information on the firebase realtime database. After the user signup function created, I mean `auth.createuserwithemailndpassword` function done processing, and before going to the next activity I put these lines below of code to store the all signup information. It creates user but doesn't save information on database and says app has stopped working.

```
uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UserName);
pass  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Pass);
phon  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PhoneNo);
post= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Pos);

String un,pas,ph,pos;
un = uname.getText().toString();
pas = pass.getText().toString().trim();
ph = phon.getText().toString().trim();
pos = post.getText().toString().trim();

final FirebaseUserForInformation fb = new FirebaseUserForInformation();

fb.setuN(un.trim());
fb.setPs(pas);
fb.setPhNo(ph);
fb.setPost(pos);

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users");
myRef.push().setValue(fb);
```

And my FirebaseUserForInformation class is:

```
public class FirebaseUserForInformation{
    public FirebaseUserForInformation(){
        //constructor
    }

    public void setuN(String username){this.Username = username;}
    public void setPs(String password){ this.PassWord = password;}
    public void setPhNo(String ph){
        this.phoneNumber = ph;
    }
    public void setPost(String pos){
        this.post = pos;
    }

    public String getUN(){return Username;}
    public String getPs(){return PassWord;}
    public String getPhNo(){return phoneNumber;}
    public String getposNo(){return post;}

    private String Username;
    private String PassWord;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String post;
}
```

And when I run the app it will say that the app stopped working.

Comment: Have a look at your Logcat output. What error(s) is / are coming up? You will get something like: java.io.Exception and then a stack trace. There will be: " at java..." reference to show the line where your app is crashing.

Comment: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=ClientSideMainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=1163476633528806787}]

Comment: That can't be all.. When you are viewing logcat, select within the drop-down menu on the right "Error" and then further on the right "No Filters".

Comment: 02-26 19:13:49.998 636-647/? E/BatteryStatsImpl: slot=0 bin=4 CurSlotRaw=0
02-26 19:13:52.560 636-2968/? E/BatteryStatsImpl: slot=0 bin=4 CurSlotRaw=0
02-26 19:13:55.123 636-2899/? E/BatteryStatsImpl: slot=0 bin=4 CurSlotRaw=0
02-26 19:13:57.675 636-962/? E/BatteryStatsImpl: slot=0 bin=4 CurSlotRaw=0
02-26 19:14:00.027 636-909/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 293
02-26 19:14:00.238 636-969/? E/BatteryStatsImpl: slot=0 bin=4 CurSlotRaw=0
02-26 19:14:02.800 636-647/? E/BatteryStatsImpl: slot=0 bin=4 CurSlotRaw=0

Comment: .. Is your phone or emulator on the left showing up? And there is not [DISCONNECTED] tag next to it? I don't think you are looking at the actual error log of the device that you are trying to get up and running..

Comment: My Mobile phone.

Comment: Sorry, I really want to help you, but I guess you should have a look at how to read your logcat output first. Have a look at: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Comment: Please find the stack trace and error message of the crash in your logcat and add those to your question by clicking the **edit** link underneath it.